# I want to tokenize string using the following delimiters in pig: dash, comma, hash, space and colon

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

How can I do this using STRSPLIT, TOKENIZER or any other method?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `STRSPLIT` with `regex` to solve this problem. I am not sure your input has single or multiple combination of delimiters(dash,comma,hypen,space and hash) but the below solution will work for both.

**input**

```
a#b c-d,e
f e,g#h:i
1,2,3,4,5
l#y#z#h#n
A B C D E
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'[-,:\\s#]',5));
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(a,b,c,d,e)
(f,e,g,h,i)
(1,2,3,4,5)
(l,y,z,h,n)
(A,B,C,D,E)
```

If you have only `single delimiter` in your input, say'#'  or any other delimiter that you mentioned then try the below script ( `'5'` in the third arg is total number of columns in your input)

```
 B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line,'#',5));
```

In case of `multiple delimiter`, suppose you want to add any new delimiter say `'$'` then just add this delimiter inside the `character class` of regex.

**Note**  `'$'` is  special character in Regex which needs escaping for double backslashs like this `'[\\$-,:\\s#]'`